# Real-life applications of Dynamic Logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I'm a 1st year Computer Science student and I have to write a paper on Propositional Dynamic Logic. I'm currently going through Harel and Kozen's $Dynamic\ Logic$ and Goldblatt's $Logics\ of\ Time\ and\ Computation$. I've taken a peek at $Stanford's\ Enciclopedia\ of\ Philosophy$ articles on Dynamic Logic. Could someone give me a couple of examples of real-life applications of Dynamic Logic (exept from formalazing programs).